# How to handle parameter packs in the middle of a function signature?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I feel a bit uncomfortable at the moment when using parameter packs. I've got a function

```
template <class ... Args>
void f( int x, Args ... args, int y )
{}
```

and of course using it like this works:

```
f( 5, 3 );
```

I am wondering why the following call fails:

```
f( 5, 3.f, 3 );
```

It seems like a straight-forward use of parameter packs to me, but according to the compiler `Args` is not expanded.

Of course, I could easily replace `f` by:

```
template <class ... Args>
void f( int x, Args ... args )
{
    static_assert( sizeof...( args ) >= 1, ... );
    extract y from args ...
}
```

Questions:

- Why can't I use parameter packs like this? It seems like the compiler could easily create the replacement code. Or are there any problems with the replacement `f()` above?
- What is the best way to  deal with this, if the order of the parameters is *really* important to me? (Think of `std::transform` for an arbitrary number of input iterators.)
- Why is the usage of parameter packs not forbidden in the situation above? I assume, it is because they could be expanded explicitly, e.g. `f<float>( 5, 3.f, 3 )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't I use parameter packs like this? It seems like the compiler could easily create the replacement code. Or are there any problems with the replacement f() above?

Might be easy in this particular case, might not be in others. The real answer is that the Standard specifies the behavior and the Standard did not specify any transformation... and in general rarely does.

I would note that your transformation *does not work with SFINAE*, since `static_assert` are hard-errors, so I am *glad* the transformation is not performed. *(Hint: what if `f` is overloaded with a single-argument version taking a `float`, which would get chosen with/without transformation for `f(1)` ?)*

> What is the best way to deal with this, if the order of the parameters is really important to me? (Think of `std::transform` for an arbitrary number of input iterators.)

Explicitly specifying the template pack parameters.

> Why is the usage of parameter packs not forbidden in the situation above? I assume, it is because they could be expanded explicitly, e.g. f( 5, 3.f, 3 )?

I think that your assumption is spot on; if explicitly specified this works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of SFINAE in this case. I am quite sure that I could come up with a solution that would handle most cases correctly, but now I am also sure that it is not worth the hassle (in my situation).

Answer (score 0):

It's a case of you can have other non-variadic template parameters, but only after these non-variadic arguments have been allocated to the non-variadic parameters, can the remainders constitute the parameter pack for the variadic parameter.  So you have to move the `int y` at the end of your argument list to before the variadic parameters.  Something like:

```
template <class... Args>
void f(int x, int y, Args... args)
{}
```